# State variable React Class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I am new to react. And I'm having problem understanding why cannot we access a state variable from `document.addEventListener` in class component?

And if that is possible how it is possible?

Comment: Please share sample code.

Comment: Please, provide some about the `state` variable and its usage. The fix might be immediately apparent from seeing the code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean. You can both access and set state in a callback from addEventListener:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    clickCount: 0,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('old clicks', this.state.clickCount);
      this.setState(prev => ({
        clickCount: prev.clickCount + 1,
      }));
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.